# Proof of the duality principle in Boolean Algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, binary

I have looked at some proofs of the duality principle online, and those use a lot of algebra which I do not understand.

Is there a simple proof of the duality principle? I know the basic laws, theorems like DeMorgan's theorems, Sum of Products and Product of Sums, and Karnaugh Maps.

Comment: Please identify one of the proofs you have looked at and ask for help with the points you don't understand. We can't guess what problems you have with the proofs you have looked at so we can't guess what would be simple enough for you.

Comment: @RobArthan https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Duality_Principle_(Boolean_Algebras) - This is the proof I read. I can't understand the first line of the proof and so I can't understand any further. I haven't studied abstract algebra. Can you explain that proof in simpler terms? Thank you!

Comment: It would be good to edit your question to include the reference. In very simple terms, if you draw up the truth tables for $\land$ and $\lor$ and switch $\bot$ and $\top$ and switch $\land$ and $\lor$, then you get the same truth tables back again. (That shows that duality holds for the simplest non-trivial Boolean algebra $\Bbb{B} = \{ \top, \bot\}$.)

Comment: Maybe [this QA](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2586662/1059606) is fine although using symbols a bit different from proofwiki.