# How do I prove this logical equivalence?

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

**$\phi$ is a well formed formula.**

**f($\phi$) is given by replacing ∧ with ∨ (and vice versa) and 1 with 0 (and vice versa) in $\phi$.**

**g(f($\phi$)) is given by replacing all literals in f($\phi$) (obtained above) with their negations.**

**For all $\phi$, prove that g(f(¬ $\phi$)) is logically equivalent to $\phi$.**

From what I know, there are two ways to prove this - using truth tables, or by proving that $\phi$ ↔ g(f(¬ $\phi$)). But I find the question too vague/abstract, and I am unable to solve it using either method.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried induction on the structure of $\phi$? Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586642/proof-of-principle-of-duality-show-that-%CF%86-is-logically-equivalent-to-%C2%AC%CF%86

Comment: No I haven't, I didn't know I could use induction to prove logical equivalence. Can you help me out by stating the base case for induction?

Comment: What is your definition of a well-formed formula? I presume it says something like "$0$ and $1$ are wff, and so is a literal $A$. If $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are wff, so are $\neg\phi_1$, and $\phi_1\wedge\phi_2$, and ...". Then the base cases would be when $\phi = 0,1,$ or a literal $A$. Can you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: You are right about well formed formula.
Now I am unable to satisfy this for the base cases. When ϕ = 0, ¬ ϕ = 1, f(¬ ϕ) = 0 and g(f(¬ ϕ)) = 1. Similarly, when ϕ = 1, ¬ ϕ = 0, f(¬ ϕ) = 1 and g(f(¬ ϕ)) = 0. So I am unable to establish logical equivalence for the base cases.

Comment: Careful! You must distinguish between syntactic equality ($=$), and logical equivalence ($\equiv$). If $\phi = 0$, then $\neg \phi$ is certainly *equivalent* to $1$, but it is not *equal* to $1$---they are not the same formula, and $f$ and $g$ are functions on formulae. Your mistake is that you substitute $1$ for $\neg 0$ when evaluating $f(\neg 0)$. In fact, $f(\neg 0)$ = $\neg 1$.

Comment: So we get that $gf(\neg 0) = g(\neg 1) = \neg 1 \equiv 0$.

Comment: Thanks, you made it really clear there! It is just hard for me to 'think' like this, although it makes perfect sense when someone explains it to me. Maybe this is an intuition that has to be developed through practice.